# Legend labels to a geom_line ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the CPDS (Comparative Political Data Set - downloadable [here](http://www.cpds-data.org/images/Update2018/CPDS-1960-2016-Update-2018.xlsx)), I want to plot the variables `gov_left3`, `gov_cent3` and `gov_right3` for New Zealand. For `gov_left3`, I'm using the colour `tomato3`, for `gov_cent3` I use `blue` and for `gov_right3` `darkgreen`.
When I use `ggplot` to draw a `geom_line`, the graph is drawn perfectly, but...
- I can draw the graph nicely without the legend
- If I want a legend (that would be pretty nice), R is somehow mixing up the colours of `gov_left3` and `gov_right3` in the legend.
- If i relabel the legend labels using `scale_color_manual`, the colours are right in the legend, but wrong in the graph.

I have tried working with several commands starting with `scale`, but not coming to a solution. I guess it's really simple, but I just don't see it.
Do I maybe need to reshape my data frame from long/wide to wide/long?

```
# Import data
CPDS <- readxl::read_excel("~/Daten/CPDS.xlsx")

# Filter data
NZL <- dplyr::filter(CPDS, iso == "NZL")

# Draw geom_line -> this actually gets me the right graph and a correct legend, all I want to do now is relabel my legend
n <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data=NZL, aes(y=gov_left3, x=year, colour="tomato3"), size=0.7, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_line(data=NZL, aes(y=gov_cent3, x=year, colour="blue"), size=0.7, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_line(data=NZL, aes(y=gov_right3, x=year, colour="darkgreen"), size=0.7, linetype = "dashed")

n1 <- n + geom_vline(xintercept = 1994, color="red", size=1, alpha=0.75) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Parliamentary seat share of all parties", subtitle = "New Zealand government, 1960 to 2014",
       x="Year", y="Seat share in %", caption = "Source: CPDS") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", margin = margin(10, 0, 10, 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5), legend.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010)) +
  scale_color_identity(guide="legend")
```

Plotting n1 gets me the graph I want, but I want to change the legend. So, instead of **colour**, I want **Types of parties** as the title. Then, for *blue*, I want the label *centre*, for *tomato3* *left* and for *darkgreen* I would like *right*.

I hope I provided all informations needed to help :) Thank you!

[image]

/ Edit: According to PavoDive's help, I used the `melt` function to transform the data frame from wide to long. With the help of `dplyr`'s functions `filter` and `arrange`, I created a data frame containing the three columns *year*, *variable* and *value*, ordered by year.
[image: So far, so good, I guess]

But if I let `ggplot` draw a graph, the result is [image: this]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the results of `str(NZL)`. It seems to me that your years are factors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that by setting new values in `scale_color_*` family, but I see an underlying problem with your approach.

It seems you are working with a wide table, instead of a long one, which is giving you unwanted problems like the one you asked about. I'll use the `iris` data, because you didn't provide any reproducible data:

I'll first will get a wide table with years:

```
dt <- iris[, 1:4] # scrapped the species variable
dt$year <- 1:150 # created a year variable
```

I could plot this calling each variable (`Sepal-Length`, `Petal.Width`, etc.) on an independent `geom_line` call. But the right thing to do is converting your data from wide to long. For that I'll use `data.table::melt`:

```
require(data.table) # library(data.table) too!
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = "year") # check df2: is a long table now

# now the plotting part:

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable))+geom_line()
```

Now your plot has the adequate labels, and it is a simpler call. Of course you can rename the columns of `df2` both at the call of `melt` (arguments `variable.name` and `value.name`), or directly with `names(df2) <-`

**#### EDIT to add: ####**

To change the names and values in the legend, use this *at the end* of your ggplot chain:

```
+scale_color_discrete(labels = c("center", "right", "left"), name = "Political Orientation")
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited my post since I am still encountering a problem when plotting the data. Reformatting the frame from wide to long worked, as it seems. But I'm doing something wrong when plotting the data.. :/

Answer (score 0):

After reshaping my data from wide to long, I found out (hours later) that the column `value` was stored as character value, not numeric. Therefore, I had to convert the variable to numeric using the command 
`mNZL2$value <- as.numeric(as.character(mNZL2$value))`.

Plotted the whole thing like this:

```
ggplot(data=mNZL2, aes(x=year, y=as.numeric(value), colour=variable)) +
  geom_line(linetype="dashed", size=0.6) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1996, color="red", size=1, alpha=0.75) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(title = "Parliamentary seat share of all parties", 
       subtitle = "New Zealand government, 1960 to 2016", 
       x="Year", 
       y="Seat share in %", caption = "Source: CPDS") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", 
                                  margin = margin(10, 0, 10, 0)), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5), 
        legend.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010)) +   
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Accent", 
                     name = "Party types", 
                     labels=c("Right","Centre","Left")) + 
  annotate("segment", x = 2002, xend = 1997, y = 65, yend = 60,
           color = "red", size = 1, alpha = 0.75, arrow = arrow()) + 
  annotate("text", x = 2008, y = 65, label = "First MMP election",
           color = "red", fontface = "bold")
```

to get this:

[image]

Comment: great result! You may consider giving your code indentation and breaking of lines to enhance its readability.